# Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client "ChefNode2"

Tags: chef-infra, devops

I got stuck with bootstraping node with

Knife bootstrap chefnodeipaddress -x root -N ChefNode2

I can ssh and ping to chefnode2 and also chef-client installing on the node.
still Error like

Failed to authenticate to the chef server (http 401).
Server Response:
Failed to authenticate as 'chef-validator'. Ensure that your node_name and client key are correct.
Running handlers:
[2018-02-15T10:20:25+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2018-02-15T10:20:25+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 01 seconds
[2018-02-15T10:20:25+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2018-02-15T10:20:25+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2018-02-15T10:20:25+00:00] ERROR: 401 "Unauthorized"
[2018-02-15T10:20:25+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)

please help & suggest

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the password to access your node like,

```
$ knife bootstrap chefnodeipaddress -x root -P PASSWORD --node-name ChefNode2
```

Comment: Thanks @Demise, this worked for me for ubuntu user: knife bootstrap x.x.x.x --ssh-user ubuntu -i /root/.ssh/keytest.pem --sudo --use-sudo-password --node-name ChefNode1